# Why on Android Studio 4.0.1 have error NotAfter: Fri Jul 09 01:43:44 ICT 2021?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I have error like this picture on today. Me already restart and invalid cache, build again. So i'm still don't why like that.

[Image View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZPEY.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes..i thought im the only person who keep searching for this..i also have same issues..happened today..not sure whether its IDE issue or gradle issue since gradle cannot update..i can only proceed using offline mode..hopefully someone can check on this..

**UPDATE:**

checked the issue, im not sure how but on my build.gradle i just change this:

Before:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
```

After:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    }
```

Comment: oh, it's work. me already trying and my problem it's solve

Comment: i think for my case it have detail error like image in this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HUXPnh-IGXETT2rhYYfK1ETcx5yeI05l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this worked for me as well. Android studio version. 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I also have same issues too. My friend sent me a solution like below.

If you using OneSignal on your project I think it may be help you.

```
implementation ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

edit it on gradle app.

Answer (score 0):

This means that one of your dependencies has an issue with the version, go to your app gradle and check if there is a .+ on any of your dependencies and just update it to the latest version, this should solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try to set disable offline mode, then re-sync -> re,build

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhVBN.png